# trigger javascript doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I develop in ASP and I use jquery .

I am unable to use the trigger function on page load .

My change function works but not when I call loading

```
$(function () {
    $(<%= C36.ClientID %>).trigger("change");
});

<%-- C36 --%>
$(<%= C36.ClientID %>).change(function () {
    if ($(<%= C36.ClientID %>).val())
        Maj_AlertCFE('NoDest', '0');
    else
        Maj_AlertCFE('NoDest', '1');        
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is working as is you should be able to simply do:

```
$(<%= C36.ClientID %>).change(function () {
    if ($(this).val())
        Maj_AlertCFE('NoDest', '0');
    else
        Maj_AlertCFE('NoDest', '1');
//trigger change now        
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ClientID` returns the "id" attribute of the element as it is rendered on the client. So if that id is, for example "myid", your jQuery statement will render like this:

```
$(myid).trigger("change");
```

Unless you have a Javascript variable named `myid` this code will obviously fail.

What you really need is this:

```
$("#myid").trigger("change");
```

So you need to add in the quotes and # character to your statements:

```
$("#<%= C36.ClientID %>").trigger("change");
```